# How to disable spell checking in code regions in RMD files (Markdown, knitr, R)

Tags: r, vim, markdown, spell-checking, knitr

I am using the Vim-R-plugin to edit files containing markdown and R-code blocks such that the files can be complied using knitr. The filetype is: RMD. I have enabled spell checking.  How can I disable the spell checking within the code blocks?

Answer (score 5):

Spell checking is attached to certain *syntax groups*. Find the `:syn region` that covers the R code blocks, and append / edit in `contains=@NoSpell`.

Comment: Only found a /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/r.vim but no rmd.vim. Am I looking at the wrong place?

Comment: Check with `:setlocal syntax?` and `:scriptnames`.

Comment: Definitely put me on the right track, thanks. Found the `~/.vim/bundle/R-plugin/syntax/rmd.vim` file, found two respected `syntax region` (here being called `rmdChunk` and `rmdrInline` and changed `contains=@R,rmdChunkDelim` to `contains=@NoSpell,@R,rmdChunkDelim`.  Sadly, `:set ft=rmd` and even starting vim anew had no effect.  Spell checking was disabled in knitr-chunks anyway, and r code is still spell checked (also inline).  Seems as if `rmd.vim` is pulling in `markdown.vim`. Copied this file to `~/.vim/syntax/` and appended `@NoSpell` to the `syn region markdownCode`-region. No Effect :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to get the @NoSpell working by region, my approach is to toggle between languages.

I work in three languages which are set up to [toggle with a function key](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Toggle_spellcheck_with_function_keys) where I include "nospell". This makes  turning spellchecking on and off as easy as pressingt F7. When coding and writing nospell is turned on, when finalizing the edits I toggle to the appropriate language.

In fact, I find spellchecks in my code to be a plus. I make mistakes in the comment sections too, sometimes even in variable names/plot lables etc. This way you have a quick last check of all language items that are going to be visible .

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work on OS X by editing the ~/.vim/syntax/R.vim and doing a search and replace of all instances of @Spell to @NoSpell. Then restarting vim. All the red underscores were gone from the code chunks but were still in the rest of the the rmarkdown.

Interestingly this has not effected the spell checking in pure R documents that have a .R extension, so I having thought I understood what I was doing perhaps I have to admit I don't fully. But at least it has turned off spell checking of the code chunks in rmarkdown (Rmd) documents while leaving it still working elsewhere in the document.